# Dynamic Update of JSON In SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, case, sql-server-2016

[image]

One of the column I have, have values like this. If my JSON has key *id* then update its value to new one, if my JSON JSON has key *workload* then update its value to new one
Like this, I have multiple entries to update with the new values.

Currently, I am trying to loop into the table, parsing one JSON value at a time. I have tried using CASE statements.

```
BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
    select key_value  from @Template
        where key_type = 5

    OPEN @MyCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
    INTO @MyField

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

      update @Template
      set key_value =
      case 
      when 'id' in (select [key] from openjson(@MyField))
      then 
        JSON_MODIFY(@MyField, '$.id', '1')

      when 'workload' in (select [key] from openjson(@MyField))
      then 
        JSON_MODIFY(@MyField, '$.workload', '5')

      ELSE '3'
      END 
      -- Fetch next
      FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
      INTO @MyField 
    END; 
    CLOSE @MyCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```

This gives the result as below

[image]

Please suggest what have I done wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you don't need a cursor, just update statements:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   key_index int,
   key_value nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (key_index, key_value)
VALUES
   (0, N'{"id": 219002, "name": "provider", "protokol": "htpps"}'),
   (1, N'{"srp": "srp", "workload": "2"}')
```

Statement with multiple updates:

```
UPDATE d
SET d.key_value = JSON_MODIFY(d.key_value, '$.id', 1)
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.key_value) j
WHERE j.[key] = 'id'
UPDATE d
SET d.key_value = JSON_MODIFY(d.key_value, '$.workload', '5')
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.key_value) j
WHERE j.[key] = 'workload'

-- or

UPDATE Data
SET key_value = JSON_MODIFY(
    key_value, 
    '$.id', 
    CASE WHEN JSON_VALUE(key_value, 'lax $.id') IS NOT NULL THEN 2 END
)
UPDATE Data
SET key_value = JSON_MODIFY(
    key_value, 
    '$.workload', 
    CASE WHEN JSON_VALUE(key_value, 'lax $.workload') IS NOT NULL THEN '5' END
)
```

Statement with nested `JSON_MODIFY()` calls:

```
UPDATE Data
SET 
   key_value = JSON_MODIFY(
      JSON_MODIFY(
         key_value, 
         '$.id', 
         CASE WHEN JSON_VALUE(key_value, 'lax $.id') IS NOT NULL THEN 2 END
      ),
      '$.workload', 
      CASE WHEN JSON_VALUE(key_value, 'lax $.workload') IS NOT NULL THEN '5' END
   )
```

Result:

```
key_index   key_value
0           {"id": 1, "name": "provider", "protokol": "htpps"}
1           {"srp": "srp", "workload": "5"}
```

Comment: I have multiple values, so for that I will need multiple update statements. I am trying to minimize those multiple updates

Comment: What is the count of these multiple values?

Comment: Around 15 to 20

Comment: Nested `JSON_MODIFY()` calls are also an option, but the statement will become complicated.

Comment: Well, Nested makes it too complicated, I will go with multiple updates then. Thank you so much!

Comment: @PriyankaKhairnar Glad to help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210206/discussion-between-priyanka-khairnar-and-zhorov).